# Set default proxyMode for spring

Tags: spring, serialization, cglib

To serialize the session of my spring webapplication i have to change my annotations from

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
```

to

```
@Controller
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

is it possible to change the default proxyMode in applicationContext.xml?

Comment: Generally a request scoped controller is not the best idea, why do you need this instead of a singleton in the first place?

Comment: To map values of serveral input fields

Comment: But why? That should be on a model object instead of the controller?

Comment: and where should i store the model?

Comment: Why would you need to store it? It should be part of your method signature and each request will automatically get a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am terribly late on this question, but still would be useful for other people.

You can set up default proxy mode in the XML also.

```
<beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.example" scoped-proxy="interfaces"/>
</beans>
```

You can change the value of the `scoped-proxy` attribute as per your need.

This can also be done using annotation, in a spring boot application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example", scopedProxy = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-scanning-scope-resolver